# Map out SQL Server 2008 usage? (from logs)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

All-

I'm trying to determine which SQL databases are currently being used the most (as well as what applications are requesting information from them).

Is there a log analyzing tool?  Or something built into SQL server that could help me achieve this?

Ideally I'd like to show a map of server usage and understand which applications are actually hitting them.

Thanks!

Comment: [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(v=sql.100).aspx) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

[`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) shows exactly how many time each index/table was read/scanned/updated since the server started up. This is the most important piece of information since everything else (IO, RAM, CPU) can be ultimately traced to these operations. The one information not revealed from here is blocking and contention, for which a good starting point is [`sys.dm_os_wait_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx). And finally there is [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) which will drill down to the individual query CPU and execution times.

Answer (score 2):

If you right-click on the server in Management Studio you will see a 'Reports' option. There are a lot of built in reports which might give you what you need (the 'Server Dashboard' report in particular shows which databases are consuming the most CPU and I/O).

Alternatively the [Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) provides a lot of (perhaps too much) valuable data.

Comment: +1 for the reports, they're a very good starting point specially for someone not comfortable digging directly into the DMVs. I wouldn't agree on using the profiler for such a purpose though as it has a very heavy impact.

Comment: @RemusRusanu - The OP did ask how to find "...what applications are requesting information from them". The profiler would give him that as long as he's not running it all the time; even then I thought you could run the profiler on a separate machine and not loading the server too much, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @Tony: it doesn't matter where you run the profiler from,  the impact is still huge. And besides the profiler gives *events*, not aggregate stats. There are many many better tools to analyze usage pattern and load. Using profiler for this task is just a typical case of 'I only know how to use a hammer, so everything looks like a nail to me'.

Comment: Sadly I never noticed the reports option, provides some great info!  I I shouldn't use Profiler to find out what applications are hitting the database, is there another recommendation?  Maybe use something like netstat to see what source IPs are hitting the machine?  I'm not sure of the best method here